# Path.GetDirectoryName returns null on UNC path

Tags: c#, .net

```
Path.GetDirectoryName(@"C:\\");
```

returns null and

```
Path.GetDirectoryName(@"C:\\Foo");
```

returns C:\

While this is exactly the behaviour mentioned in the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getdirectoryname%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) I'm wondering why

```
Path.GetDirectoryName(@"\\server.domain.tld\Foo");
```

returns null and not as I'd have expected \server.domain.tld\

Does anyone have clue why?

Comment: Does this path exists?

Comment: Conspiracy Theory #1: the API designers harborded a secret desire to inflict confusion and subtle bugs on future developers trying to deal with Windows *and* UNC paths using the same code..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically, the UNC path structure is `\\{server}\{share}\{path.....}`, so `"Foo"` in your UNC example is equivalent to the `"C:\"` of your first example. This is why you get `null` for the path of your UNC example.

The path of `"\\server\foo\bar"` would be `"bar"`

Comment: This has to be one of the most confusing / unhelpful API for trying to deal with UNC, especially since `Path.GetDirectoryName(@"\\server\share\path")` *returns* the UNC server and share ("\\server\share") .. but, wait "those are established as as 'not directories"!

Comment: I agree.. and in 2017 / fw 4.6.x this *bug* still exists in the IO library !